# Cannot override exisitng dataframe values while replacing values in columns (strings)

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe in pandas with customers IDs and their gender. However, while cleaning the dataset I noticed that some IDs have two genders assigned, in most cases it is Female or Male and Unknown.

The df looks like this:

```
 index   ID    gender
   0     23      M
   1     23      U
   2     55      F
   3     55      U
```

My aim is to locate IDs that have two genders assigned and replace the U gender with the non-U gender.

To do this, I am using a for loop over a list, in which I have all customer IDs that have inconsistent genders. For example, for ID = 23 the code inside the loop would look like this:

```
if all((customers.loc[customers['ID'] == 23]['gender'].str.contains('M')) | (customers.loc[customers['ID'] == 23]['gender'].str.contains('U'))):
    customers.loc[customers['ID'] == 23]['gender'] = customers.loc[customers['ID'] == 23]['gender'].replace('U', 'M')
```

My problems:

1. Not sure if the for loop and if statements are optimal to perform my task
2. While using my method I am not able to override the existing dataframe. I tried using replace(inplace = True), I tried assigning the new genders as above using .loc(), but also with chained indexing. In all cases I am receiving a warning (while using .loc or chained indexing):

   ```
   A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
   Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
   See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas- 
   docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
   ```

(while using replace(inplace = True)

```
    C:\Users\***: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
    A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame
```

and the original dataframe is intact.

I looked at the StackOverflow extensively, but I still cannot solve my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A loop will be inefficient for this task. Instead, you can use `groupby`. Here's one solution which relies on sorting.

Note that with an ascending sort `NaN` appears below `M` and `F`.

```
res = df.copy()

res['gender'] = res.replace('U', np.nan\
                   .sort_values('gender')\
                   .groupby('ID')['gender'].transform('first')\
                   .fillna('U')\
                   .sort_values('index')

print(res)

   index  ID gender
0      0  23      M
1      1  23      M
2      2  55      F
3      3  55      F
```

---

In this specific case, as mentioned by @pshep123, since `U` appears alphabetically after `M` and `F` you can take the groupwise minimum:

```
res['gender'] = res.groupby('ID')['gender'].transform('min')
```

Comment: Thank you, this works fine. 
However, I have cases where two genders are M and F. Males contributes to around 70% of all customers and Females to 25%. Therefore, I wanted to assigned gender in such a case based on probability (with 0.7 it will be a man, or with 0.25 probability it will be a women). 
Do you know, if such probability-based assignmend can be done without for loop and generatiing in each intereation a new random variable?
Mybe this qualifies for a new questions?

Comment: If it's just ID and gender, couldn't you just do `.groupby('ID').min().reset_index(drop = True)`?  Given that "U" is greater than both "M" and "F".

Comment: @pshep123, You are right, that's clever, have updated, it's very specific to this application though (which may be fine).

Comment: @Bonzogondo, It really depends, this is a fairly large extension to your original question. The relevant questions are: how are the probabilities calculated? are they groupwise probabilities? I suggest you have a go yourself and ask a new question if you get stuck.

Comment: Yes, it would have to be exactly as the question posted and not great for a dataframe with other columns